# Отправка сообщения на стену ВК с помощью wall.post

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Добрый вечер. Добавляю запись на стену с помощью такого кода:

```
<script src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   VK.init({apiId: ''});

   //Данный код публикует запись на стену
   VK.Api.call('wall.post', {owner_id: '', message: "Привет"}, function (data) {
     if (data.response) {
       alert('Запись успешно добавлена!');
     }
}); 

</script>
```

Все работает замечательно, но только при каждом размещении появляется окно для подтверждения размещения записи. Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли каким-то образом избавиться от этого окна?

Comment: Окно подтверждения с капчей?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя.
Сделано специально для того, чтобы люди не могли захламлять стены автоматическими постами.